# When we say that $x^2$ = -4, would x = $\pm$2i or 2i?

Tags: complex-numbers

I saw a problem on Brilliant.org recently that sparked quite a heated discussion. The question was: Compute $\sqrt{-4} * \sqrt{-9}$. Now, If $\sqrt{-4}$ = 2i, the answer can only be -6. However, if $\sqrt{-4}$ = $\pm$2i, the answer can be $\pm$6. What would be the correct answer to this question?

Let me also say this: If we can split $\sqrt{-4}$ to $\sqrt{-1}*\sqrt{4}$, can we write the value of $\sqrt{-4}$ as $\pm$2i?

Comment: I think you've given a reasonable answer: "If $\sqrt{-4} = 2i$, the answer can only be $-6$. However, if $\sqrt{-4} = \pm2i$, the answer can be $\pm6$."

Comment: What does $x^2=4i$ have to do with $\sqrt{-4}\sqrt{-9}$?

Comment: @arctictern I messed my title up, sorry. It should have been $x^2$ = 4

Comment: But $x^2=4$ corresponds to $\pm\sqrt{4}=\pm2$, no imaginaries. You mean $x^2=-4$? The notation $\sqrt{u}$ by the way doesn't generally represent *both* solutions to $x^2=u$ (since then it wouldn't be a function), so asking about $\sqrt{u}$ and asking about the solutions to $x^2=u$ are not 100% equivalent.

Comment: @arctictern Yes, sorry I  keep screwing up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a silly thing to argue about because there's no standard definition of the square root for negative numbers. For nonnegative numbers there's no problem: we *define* $\sqrt{4}$ to be the positive number $x$ that solves $x^2=4$. This definition breaks down more generally because there's no natural extension of "positive" and "negative" to non-real numbers. If you like, you can create your own definition:

> For $a\in\mathbb R$, let $\sqrt{a}$ be the solution to $x^2=a$ whose real and imaginary parts are both nonnegative.

This looks reasonable to me; the problem is it's not a standard definition that everyone has accepted like in the $a\geq0$ case.

**Edit:** Another answer mentions the "principal branch" of the square-root function. The problem with this, and the reason there's confusion about the square root of negative numbers, is that the principal branch of $\sqrt{z}$ avoids the ray $(-\infty,0]$ in the complex plane. For any other complex number $z$, there's a standard choice of square root:
$$z^{1/2}=|z|^{1/2}e^{i\theta/2}$$
where $\theta\in(-\pi,\pi)$ is the angle $z$ makes with the positive real axis. Of course the negative real numbers correspond to values of $z$ with $\theta=\pm\pi$, which is outside of its domain. Depending on which sign of $\pi$ you use, you get different signs for $z^{1/2}$. The reason mathematicians decline to make such a choice is because the square root function would necessarily cease to be continuous (and in particular, complex analytic) at this branch cut.

Comment: Okay, so it's just a matter of definition then. There's no solid answer to this. Thanks

Comment: @megadarkfriend It kind of depends who is your audience. In Highschool and developmental algebra courses in college use the introduction $i=\sqrt{-1}$ because it "solves" the issue of taking squareroots of negative numbers. The far majority of those students will never go on taking more serious math courses where complex numbers arise again. If you however take a look at a complex variables book, then you will find introductions like $i$ is the imaginary unit for which $i^2=-1$ or some other form similar. In other words, their introduction is more formal...

Comment: I'm not sure I'd say there's no standard definition.  There is an agreed-upon principal branch of the square root function.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury You are right but the principal branch of the square root function avoids the non-positive real numbers so that's not helpful.

Comment: @imranfat  but $(i)^2=(i)^2$ and we can't take $2$ values for one value, can we? That's not a rhetorical question, I would greatly appreciate an explanation.

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla $i^2=-1$ is not an equation to be solved, it is a definition. That is where a lot of my students go wrong, and I think that is where your confusion lies.

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla Maybe the confusion is if you extend the field $\mathbb R$ with a solution to $x^2+1=0$, you necessarily get a second number that also satisfies the same equation. However these two roots are in every way symmetrical, so there's really no decision to make as far as which one we call $i$.

Comment: Hmm, that makes sense. But we would have to call one of them $i$  otherwise problems like rotate $x+yi$ counterclockwise 90 degrees would not have a common path of solution? Right, or am I still confusing something? @StanCoreyCarter

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla The only arbitrary decision that had to be made was whether we would say $i$ is at the point $(0,1)$ or $(0,-1)$ in the complex plane, thus giving multiplication by $x+iy$ a different geometric meaning.

Answer (score -1):

There's a 3rd way to interpret $\sqrt{-4}*\sqrt{-9}$. Since $-4*-9=36$, couldn't one combine the values under the radicals to get $\sqrt{36}$? Then the answer is 6.
The moral of the story is: it all depends on context and how you define your notation.

Comment: I couldn't disagree with you more...:)

Comment: Your manipulation permits the following "proof": $-1=i\cdot i=\sqrt{-1}\sqrt{-1}=\sqrt{(-1)\cdot(-1)}=\sqrt{1}=1$.